# if insert works then

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, sql-update, sql-insert

so im trying to check if a table entry is equal to another table entry and if it is 
update the table
and if it is not put a new entry in

im getting errors at the if exists? Ive tried moving the begins and ends around to no avail.

```
BEGIN    
    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT  *    
        FROM x, y    
        WHERE x.ID = y.ID
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO x(ID, sID,cID, n, a)
    VALUES(y.ID, y.sID, y.cID, NULL, NULL)
END
BEGIN
    ELSE
        UPDATE x 
        SET x.sID= y.sID, x.cID= y.cID
    END  
END
;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want the `insert ... on duplicate key` syntax:

```
insert into x(id, sid, cid, n, a)
select y.id, y.sid, y.cid, null, null
from y
on duplicate key update x.sid = y.sid, x.cid = y.cid
```

This query attempts to insert all existing rows in `y` in table `x`. When an already existing `id` is met, the query goes to the `on duplicate key` clause, and `update`s `sid` and `cid` on the existing row.

For this to work, you need a unique (or primary key) constraint on `x(id)`.